# ¿Cómo puedo mejorar el rendimiento de mi aplicativo?

Tags: android, json, hilos, app, rendimiento

Mi aplicación funciona OK pero al desplegar uno de los Activity se demora mucho tiempo y obtengo el siguiente mensaje:

> I/Choreographer: Skipped 66 frames! The application may be doing too
>   much work on its main thread

Coloqué mensajes por consola y CREO que el problema radica en la lectura del JSON

este es mi segmento de código dentro en onCreate donde se demora:

```
listaRutas = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvwRutas);
        int id = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("puesto_id");
        ArrayList<Sentido> sentidos = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            jsonArraySentidos = new JSONArray(controladorSentidos.getSentidosXControl(id));
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArraySentidos.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonArraySentidos.getJSONObject(i);
                int id_sentido = jsonChildNode.optInt("s_id");
                String nombre_sentido = jsonChildNode.optString("s_nombre");
                String servicio = jsonChildNode.optString("s_tipo_servicio");
                if (servicio.equals("BASICO")){
                    sentidos.add(new Sentido(id_sentido, nombre_sentido, R.drawable.basico));
                }else{
                    sentidos.add(new Sentido(id_sentido, nombre_sentido, R.drawable.berlinave));
                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        ControladorVehiculos controladorVehiculos = new ControladorVehiculos();
        JSONArray jsonArrayVehiculos;
         vehiculos = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            jsonArrayVehiculos = new JSONArray(controladorVehiculos.getVehiculos());
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArrayVehiculos.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonArrayVehiculos.getJSONObject(i);
                String placa = jsonChildNode.optString("v_placa");
                String numero = jsonChildNode.optString("v_numero");
                vehiculos.add(new Vehiculo(placa, numero));
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        ControladorConductores controladorConductores = new ControladorConductores();
        JSONArray jsonArrayConductores;

        conductores = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            jsonArrayConductores = new JSONArray(controladorConductores.getConductores());
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArrayConductores.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonArrayConductores.getJSONObject(i);
                Long cedula = jsonChildNode.optLong("c_cedula");
                String nombre = jsonChildNode.optString("c_nombre");
                conductores.add(new Conductor(cedula, nombre));
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        AdaptadorSentidos adaptadorSentidos = new AdaptadorSentidos(getApplicationContext(), sentidos);
        listaRutas.setAdapter(adaptadorSentidos);
        listaRutas.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int posicion, long l) {
                Sentido s = (Sentido) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(posicion);
                Log.d("CLIC EN: ", "ID: " + s.getId() + " NOMBRE: " + s.getNombre());
                iniciar(usuario, puesto, s);
            }
        });
```

Esta es mi Clase ConexionJSON

```
public class ConexionJSON {

    public String call(String url) {
        Log.d("Lectura de CADENA ", "Iniciar leyendo");
        int BUFFER_SIZE = 2000;
        InputStream in = null;
        try {
            Log.d("Lectura de CADENA ", "antes del OpenHttpConnection");
            in = OpenHttpConnection(url);
            Log.d("Lectura de CADENA ", "despues del OpenHttpConnection");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("ERROR: ", e.getMessage() + ": MENSAJE: ERROR AL CREAR CONEXION  OpenHttpConnection ");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "";
        }
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(in);
        int charRead;
        String str = "";
        char[] inputBuffer = new char[BUFFER_SIZE];
        try {
            Log.d("Lectura de CADENA ", "antes del while");
            while ((charRead = isr.read(inputBuffer)) > 0) {
                String readString = String.copyValueOf(inputBuffer, 0, charRead);
                str += readString;
                inputBuffer = new char[BUFFER_SIZE];
            }
            in.close();
            Log.d("Lectura de CADENA ", "despues del while");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("ERROR: ", e.getMessage() + ": MENSAJE: ERROR AL LLAMAR LA URL ");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "";
        }
        return str;
    }

    private InputStream OpenHttpConnection(String url) throws IOException {
        InputStream in = null;
        int response = -1;
        URL url1 = new URL(url);
        URLConnection conn = url1.openConnection();
        if (!(conn instanceof HttpURLConnection))
            throw new IOException("NO HAY UNA Http Connection");
        try {
            HttpURLConnection httpconn = (HttpURLConnection) conn;
            httpconn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
            httpconn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
            httpconn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            httpconn.connect();

            response = httpconn.getResponseCode();
            if (response == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                in = httpconn.getInputStream();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("ERROR: ", e.getMessage() + ": ERROR DE CONEXION");
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new IOException("Error al conectar");
        }
        return in;
    }
}
```

Y esta es una de mis clases que uso para realizar las consultas, ControladorConductores y ControladorSentidos son muy parecidas a esta:

```
public class ControladorVehiculos extends ConexionJSON{
    String URL = "http://MIIPPPUBLICA:8000/Controles/vehiculo.php";
    String url = "";
    String response = "";

    public String getVehiculos() {
        try {
            url = URL + "?dato=getvehiculos";
            System.out.println("llamando a... URL vehiculos: " + url);
            response = call(url);
            System.out.println("Respuesta de.. URL vehiculos: " + url);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("ERROR APP EN : ", e.getMessage() + ": getVehiculos en ControladorVehiculos ");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return response;
    }
}
```

Comment: Lo mejor es hacer que algunos procesos corren en asyncTask ya que saturas el thread principal y tambien mirate lo de google components arquitech

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Las peticiones a servicios externos (Internet) o que realicen mucha lógica que interrumpa el thread de la UI deben manejarse en un hilo separado (background).

### Te recomiendo que leas un poco sobre [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Para tu caso, el `AsyncTask` encaja perfecto, el método `call` de tu clase `ConexionJSON` es el causante del bloqueo.

Trata de pasar esa llamada al servicio en background, que sería el `doInBackground` del `AsyncTask`, y cuando obtengas la respuesta usa `onPostExecute`

Comment: Esta es deberia ser considerada la respuesta correcta. Ese es el causante de tus problemas. Adicional a ello me gustaria decir que puedes checar las co rutinas de kotlin, lo cual es una acercamiento mucho mejor en mi opinion en caso de que te animes a usar kotlin para tu desarollo.